# User right based on Local Users and Groups

Tags: windows-7, permissions

What is difference when one creates new user in Windows 7/10. It's clear when it's user type is added to "Administrators" group. It's clear if it belongs to "Users". But what is this user is in both - Users and Administrators groups at once ? Is it sum of both groups - so in fact has higher right from Administrators or is it lowered to normal user by "Users" ?

Is looking at analogy with granting NTFS permission to resources - when "deny" right has higher importance than "allow" correct here ?

Answer (score 2):

> But what if the user is in both the Users and Administrators groups at once?
>
> Is it sum of both groups - so in fact has higher right from Administrators or is it lowered to normal user by "Users"?

## Explicit deny permissions take precedence over everything else.

The hierarchy of precedence for NTFS permissions can be summarized as follows, in order from highest to lowest priority:

- Explicit Deny
- Explicit Allow
- Inherited Deny
- Inherited Allow

[image]

The net effect in this example would be for the Administrator account to be denied access, as an Explicit Deny privilege is 1st in the hierachy of precedence, while an Inherited Allow is 4th (and even an *Explicit* Allow is still only 2nd):

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you then tried to override the deny permissions by clicking `Continue`, you would be confronted with the following message and forced to manually remove the explicit deny permission from the Security tab in order to regain access.

This occurs because no amount of allow permissions have the power to override an explicit deny permission:

[image]

Comment: I think the *essence* of what the OP said boiled down to just a single question really: which permission "wins" when an Allow and a Deny conflict? That seems to be what he was scratching his head over! 

Comment: A nice summary, if only about filesystem ACLs. User rights involve a little more than that.

Comment: Thanks 4 explain, but I asked rather about Users and Groups - what is 1 user is in both groups in context of: will he be able to install programs, create new users, etc - not strictly about NFTS permissions. NTFS permissions I used as analogy :)

Comment: In that case you'd still have Administrator rights. I thought your focus was more on the effect on file permissions specifically rather than installing software, based on "Is looking at analogy with granting NTFS permission to resources".

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation. Now it's clear.